# Slider component in WP8 won't move

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a `Slider` component in my WP7 and WP8 app. In WP7, the `Slider` moves according to its `Scheduler`, but in WP8, it simply just won't move.

The `Slider` is styled, and I know there is some changes in WP8. First of all, what exactly are those changes and what do I change in code? The documentation from Microsoft is poor. Anyone got an idea of what this can be, maybe other than the changes from Microsoft?

And even if I set the default value to something, the thumb will always be in its starting position. I can't move it either.

For me, this applies to a various different styles, e.g. from [Mifrosofts own Slider Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

This one has a template:

```
        <Slider x:Name="Slider" IsHitTestVisible="true" Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,24,0,0" Template="{StaticResource SliderControlTemplate1}" />
```

Here is the template:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderControlTemplate1" TargetType="Slider">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrack"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrack"/>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalFill">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalFill">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalFill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrack" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0" Opacity="0.2"/>
                <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeDecreaseRepeatButton" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource PhoneSimpleRepeatButton}"/>
                <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeIncreaseRepeatButton" Grid.Column="2" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource PhoneSimpleRepeatButton}"/>
                <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalCenterElement" Grid.Column="1" Height="12" Margin="0" Width="12">
                    <Thumb.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid ManipulationDelta="ProgressBarManipulationDelta" Width="46" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Source="/slider.png"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Thumb.Template>
                </Thumb>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And I have tried a corresponding Style. What could be the problem? Should I use `Style` or `Template`? Both acts equally for me now..

Comment: Does your code work if you remove the template? If so that could indicate that the internal structure of the control has changed in WP8 such that your template isn't valid anymore. Try and do a diff of a new copy of the WP8 Slider template in Expression Blend and what you have.

Comment: Yes, it works without the template. That is true what you are saying,and Microsoft is saying the same with this: In Windows Phone 8, the Slider control and its API have changed significantly.
HorizontalLargeIncrease, HorizontalLargeDecrease, HorizontalThumb, VerticalLargeIncrease, VerticalLargeDecrease, and VerticalThumb have been removed from the control template.
The corresponding new template parts are HorizontalFill, HorizontalTrack, and HorizontalCenterElement, VerticalFill, VerticalTrack, and VerticalCenterElement.The new template parts are all of type FrameworkElement.

But what to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue. Before WP8, we had edited a copy of its original style and modified it to our purposes. Later, when upgrading the project to WP8 this modified style from WP7 caused the slider not getting updated anymore as the style has changed since. Removing the style fixed it. In case the modifications are still needed, you should get the original style from WP8's slider component.